# Vue Unhead generates warnining "[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components. "

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata, vue-composition-api, unheadvue

I'm trying to use [the Unhead library](https://unhead.unjs.io/) in a Vue 3 project, it works fine however I keep getting this Vue warning originating from a view component

> [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

I followed [these instructions](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/installation) to install and setup the library and it looks like so in my file :

**main.js**

```js
import { createHead } from '@unhead/vue';
...

const app = createApp(App);
const head = createHead();


app.use(router);
app.use(store);
...
app.use(head);

app.mount('#app');
```

and I'm using the [`useSeoMeta` composable](https://unhead.unjs.io/usage/composables/use-seo-meta) like so in an article view

**ArticleView.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { useSeoMeta } from '@unhead/vue';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import knowledgeAPI from '@/services/knowledgeAPI.js';
...

const route = useRoute();

const articleData = ref(null);

/* sharability enhancements */
onMounted(async () => {
  // fetching data after mounting to trigger loading status 
  articleData.value = await knowledgeAPI.getArticleById(route.params.id);

  // adding meta tags for this view
  useSeoMeta({
    title: articleData.value.title,
    ogTitle: articleData.value.title,
    twitterTitle: articleData.value.title,
    description: articleData.value.summary,
    ogDescription: articleData.value.summary,
    twitterDescription: articleData.value.summary,
    ogImage: articleData.value.img,
    twitterImage: articleData.value.img,
    twitterCard: 'summary',
    ogSiteName: 'MySite'
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `inject()` in the code provided

Comment: error comes from useSeoMeta which uses `inject` internally.  it's telling you that you can't use `useSeoMeta({ ... })` in the `onMounted` hook.  It must be used inside `setup()` (or just top-level of script setup).  Therefore, try using it outside of onMounted function.  [The composable is reactive](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/how-it-works) so can still receive values from async functions and reactively update once the values are received.

Comment: **Thank** **you** @yoduh for your comment, indeed using `useSeoMeta({...})` in the `onMounted` hook caused the issue, following your tip I checked [the recommended way](https://unhead.unjs.io/setup/vue/how-it-works) of using Vue reactivity from the documentation and it worked like a charm, if you can post your comment as an answer so it can be marked as a solution that'd be great.